# Loading R libraries in a single knitr chunk valid for the full document

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How can I load a R library in a single knitr chunk but valid for all the chunks of the full document.

````
Start the document.

// First chunk
```{r}
library(tidyverse)

```
Here, some more lines.

// Second chunk
 ```{r}
library(tidyverse) // Instead of loading the library again some way to 
                  // do it only once

```
````

Comment: This should be how it works already? Everything carries across chunks when knitting. Can you explain exactly why you think that loading in the first chunk doesn't work?

Comment: I would be interested to know who started the rumor loading a library for each chunk is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, sorry.The loading of the library in the first chunk carry across the rest. Something different went wrong in my first trial.Should I remove this post?